# iOS Facebook SDK isSessionValid returning null

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

With the Facebook iOS SDK code below, the log is always "(null)"

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxx" andDelegate:self];

NSLog(@"%@", [facebook isSessionValid]);
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 3):

%@ is your problem.  `BOOL`'ean values are not objects, so %@ is not their string literal.  Strangely enough, `BOOL`'s are `signed char` but can't be NSlog'd as such.  Here's how you would do it:

```
NSLog([facebook isSessionValid] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether your facebook session is  valid or not, type

```
NSLog(@"facebook session status: %d", [facebook isSessionValid]);
```

It will print the YES/TRUE and NO/FALSE value into 1 and 0 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the Facebook object doesn't create a Facebook session. Once you have the Facebook object, you can call the -(void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions method, which will prompt the user to login, either through the Facebook app, Safari, or a popup (whichever is available in that order). Once the user successfully logs in, the session will have been created and the [facebook isSessionValid] call should return YES.

Comment: That does not explain a NULL NSLog.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The BOOL in the NSLog is a problem as well. With both of our answers I think the underlying issues should be thoroughly covered.